# Implement a capped and buffered job executor

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, manualresetevent, taskcompletionsource

I want to implement a capped and buffered job executor.

It will have a single method:

```
public class CappedBufferedExecutor {
  public CappedBufferedExecutor(int bufferCapping, int fillTimeInMillisec);
  public Task<bool> EnqueueAsync(string val);
}
```

The idea is that values are asynchronously enqueued, and once `fillTimeInMillisec` milliseconds pass, or the buffer is filled to its cap of **unique** values, the execution is made in practice and the async tasks all complete. While the execution is done (which could take a long time), the buffer can be re-filled and new async executions can be made.

I thought of something in the lines of the following pseudo code

- Using a `Timer`, wait for the `fillTime` to pass, once elapsed, create a new task, that will do the work (see below).
- On new value, lock a `rwlock` for read. Check if buffer is full, if so wait on a `ManualResetEvent` or a `TaskCompletionSource`.
- Add new value to buffer (`HashSet<string>`).
- If buffer is full, create a new execution task, that will lock the `rwlock` for write, do the work on all collected values and wake up all pending tasks using a `TaskCompletionSource`.
- Wait on the `TaskCompletionSource` for the buffered task (mentioned in previous step) to be executed.

My problems: how to synchronize the `Timer` and the filled buffer check, how to wait when buffer is full, how to switch between `TaskCompletionSource` instances when starting to execute and allowing new values to arrive.

Comment: Why do you need to return `Task<bool>` from `EnqueueAsync`? Can it just raise an event with list of tasks when buffer is full?

Comment: What should happen if the items are still being processed and the buffer is full before it is completed?

Comment: @apocalypse The bool is to indicate wether the job succeeded. Not of importance, can go your way.

Comment: @PeterBons a new execution should be started, regardless of the current one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just concept, so don't expect much :-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var buffer = CreateBuffer (); 

            var executor = new Executor<string> (SomeWork, buffer);
            executor.ProcessingStarted += Executor_ProcessingStarted;

            string userInput = null;

            do
            {
                userInput = Console.ReadLine ();

                buffer.Enqueue (userInput);
            }
            while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (userInput));

            executor.Dispose ();
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private static IBuffer<string> CreateBuffer ()
        {
            var buffer = new UniqueItemsBuffer<string> (3);

            buffer.DataAvailable += (items) => Console.WriteLine ("BUFFER :: data available raised.");

            var alert = new Alert ();

            var bufferWithTimeout = new BufferWithTimeout<string> (buffer, alert, TimeSpan.FromSeconds (5));

            return bufferWithTimeout;
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        static Random rnd = new Random (); // must be outside, to avoid creating Random too quick because it will use the same seed for all tasks

        public static bool SomeWork (string x)
        {
            int delay = rnd.Next (1000, 8000);

            Console.WriteLine ($"  +++ Starting SomeWork for: {x}, delay: {delay} ms");

            Thread.Sleep (delay);

            Console.WriteLine ($"  --- SomeWork for: {x} - finished.");

            return true;
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private static void Executor_ProcessingStarted (IReadOnlyList<Task<bool>> items)
        {
            Task.Run (() =>
            {
                Task.WaitAll (items.ToArray ());
                Console.WriteLine ("Finished processing tasks, count = " + items.Count);
            });
        }
    }

    //====== actual code ===================================================================================================================

    public delegate void ItemsAvailable<T> (IReadOnlyList<T> items); // new type to simplify code

    public delegate bool ProcessItem<T> (T item); // processes the given item and returns true if job is done with success

    //======================================================================================================================================

    public interface IDataAvailableEvent<T>
    {
        event ItemsAvailable<T> DataAvailable; // occurs when buffer need to be processed (also before raising this event, buffer should be cleared)
    }

    //======================================================================================================================================

    public interface IProcessingStartedEvent<T>
    {
        event ItemsAvailable<Task<bool>> ProcessingStarted; // executor raises this event when all tasks are created and started
    }

    //======================================================================================================================================

    public interface IBuffer<T> : IDataAvailableEvent<T>
    {
        bool Enqueue (T item); // adds new item to buffer (but sometimes it can ignore item, for example if we need only unique items in list)
                               // returns: true = buffer is not empty, false = is emtpy

        void FlushBuffer ();   // should clear buffer and raise event (or not raise if buffer was already empty)
    }

    //======================================================================================================================================

    // raises DataAvailable event when buffer cap is reached
    // ignores duplicates

    // you can only use this class from one thread

    public class UniqueItemsBuffer<T> : IBuffer<T>
    {
        public event ItemsAvailable<T> DataAvailable;

        readonly int capacity;
        HashSet<T> items = new HashSet<T> ();

        public UniqueItemsBuffer (int capacity = 10)
        {
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }

        public bool Enqueue (T item)
        {
            if (items.Add (item) && items.Count == capacity)
            {
                FlushBuffer ();
            }

            return items.Count > 0;
        }

        public void FlushBuffer ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("BUFFER :: flush, item count = " + items.Count);

            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                var itemsCopy = items.ToList ();
                items.Clear ();

                DataAvailable?.Invoke (itemsCopy);
            }
        }
    }

    //======================================================================================================================================

    public class Executor<T> : IProcessingStartedEvent<T>, IDisposable
    {
        public event ItemsAvailable<Task<bool>> ProcessingStarted;

        readonly ProcessItem<T> work;
        readonly IDataAvailableEvent<T> dataEvent;

        public Executor (ProcessItem<T> work, IDataAvailableEvent<T> dataEvent)
        {
            this.work = work;
            this.dataEvent = dataEvent;

            dataEvent.DataAvailable += DataEvent_DataAvailable;
        }

        private void DataEvent_DataAvailable (IReadOnlyList<T> items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("EXECUTOR :: new items to process available, count = " + items.Count);

            var list = new List<Task<bool>> ();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var task = Task.Run (() => work (item));

                list.Add (task);
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("EXECUTOR :: raising processing started event (this msg can appear later than messages from SomeWork)");

            ProcessingStarted?.Invoke (list);
        }

        public void Dispose ()
        {
            dataEvent.DataAvailable -= DataEvent_DataAvailable;
        }
    }

    //======================================================================================================================================

    // if you want to fill buffer using many threads - use this decorator

    public sealed class ThreadSafeBuffer<T> : IBuffer<T>
    {
        public event ItemsAvailable<T> DataAvailable;

        readonly IBuffer<T> target;
        readonly object sync = new object ();

        private ThreadSafeBuffer (IBuffer<T> target)
        {
            this.target = target;
            this.target.DataAvailable += (items) => DataAvailable?.Invoke (items); // TODO: unpin event :P
        }

        public bool Enqueue (T item)
        {
            lock (sync) return target.Enqueue (item);
        }

        public void FlushBuffer ()
        {
            lock (sync) target.FlushBuffer ();
        }

        public static IBuffer<T> MakeThreadSafe (IBuffer<T> target)
        {
            if (target is ThreadSafeBuffer<T>) return target;

            return new ThreadSafeBuffer<T> (target);
        }
    }

    //======================================================================================================================================

    // and now if you want to process buffer after elapsed time

    public interface IAlert
    {
        CancellationTokenSource CreateAlert (TimeSpan delay, Action action); // will execute 'action' after given delay (non blocking)
    }

    // I didn't use much timers, so idk is this code good

    public class Alert : IAlert
    {
        List<System.Timers.Timer> timers = new List<System.Timers.Timer> (); // we need to keep reference to timer to avoid dispose

        public CancellationTokenSource CreateAlert (TimeSpan delay, Action action)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource ();

            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer (delay.TotalMilliseconds);
            timers.Add (timer);

            timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                timers.Remove (timer);

                timer.Dispose ();

                if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) return;

                action.Invoke ();
            };

            timer.AutoReset = false; // just one tick
            timer.Enabled = true;

            return cts;
        }
    }

    // thread safe (maybe :-D)

    public class BufferWithTimeout<T> : IBuffer<T>
    {
        public event ItemsAvailable<T> DataAvailable;

        readonly IBuffer<T> target;
        readonly IAlert     alert;
        readonly TimeSpan   timeout;

        CancellationTokenSource cts;

        readonly object sync = new object ();

        public BufferWithTimeout (IBuffer<T> target, IAlert alert, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            this.target  = ThreadSafeBuffer<T>.MakeThreadSafe (target); // alert can be raised from different thread
            this.alert   = alert;
            this.timeout = timeout;

            target.DataAvailable += Target_DataAvailable; // TODO: unpin event
        }

        private void Target_DataAvailable (IReadOnlyList<T> items)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                DisableTimer ();
            }

            DataAvailable?.Invoke (items);
        }

        public bool Enqueue (T item)
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                bool hasItems = target.Enqueue (item); // can raise underlying flush -> dataAvailable event (will disable timer)

                // and now if buffer is empty, we cannot start timer

                if (hasItems && cts == null) // if timer is not enabled
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("TIMER :: created alert");
                    cts = alert.CreateAlert (timeout, HandleAlert);
                }

                return hasItems;
            }
        }

        public void FlushBuffer ()
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                DisableTimer ();
                target.FlushBuffer ();
            }
        }

        private void HandleAlert ()
        {
            lock (sync)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("TIMER :: handler, will call buffer flush");
                target.FlushBuffer ();
            }
        }

        private void DisableTimer ()
        {
            cts?.Cancel ();
            cts = null;

            Console.WriteLine ("TIMER :: disable");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to work this for my code! small note: `System.Timers.Timer` doesn't need you to maintain a reference - its maintained by the framework :)

Comment: @Mugen: ah... true. Thanks for a tip. Looks like they fixed it in Net 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something easily using [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx). A basic example using the `Buffer` method:

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new Processor();
    c.SetupBufferedProcessor(2, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

    c.Enqueue("A");
    c.Enqueue("B");
    c.Enqueue("C");

    Console.ReadLine(); 

    // When application has ended, flush the buffer
    c.Dispose(); 
}


public sealed class Processor : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable subscription;
    private Subject<string> subject = new Subject<string>();

    public void Enqueue(string item)
    {
        subject.OnNext(item);       
    }

    public void SetupBufferedProcessor(int bufferSize, TimeSpan bufferCloseTimespan)
    {
        // Create a subscription that will produce a set of strings every second 
        // or when buffer has 2 items, whatever comes first
        subscription = subject.AsObservable()
            .Buffer(bufferCloseTimespan, bufferSize)
            .Where(list => list.Any()) // suppress empty list (no items enqueued for 1 second)
            .Subscribe(async list =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", list)); 
                    Thread.Sleep(2000); // For demo purposes, to demonstrate processing takes place parallel with other batches.
                });
            });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscription?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This will output

```
A,B
```

and, after one second,

```
C
```

The code for rx is [at GitHub](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET)
More on rx: http://www.introtorx.com/

This example can be improved to hold references to the created `Task` objects so they can be properly awaited before ending the application but this will give you the general idea.